# Automatically unzip .tgz file when downloaded

Tags: chrome, archive

When I download a zipped file from chrome, I can see a .tgz in my downloads section ... as such:
[image]

When I click on it, I get the following screen:
[image]

and then I have to manually extract it.

I don't know if this is possible or not, but I would like it so that whenever I click on a .tgz file, it opens the extracted version of it, and it's extracted in the same directory that it's present (Downloads in this case).

Comment: I would suggest that even if you think you want that, you really don't.  e.g. what if it auto-extracts over the top of an existing file or directory....or if someone has tricked you into downloaded a hacked up 50TB file of 0x01 bytes (compressed to almost nothing).   safer and easier to extract the archive manually using your preferred command line or GUI tools.